# Delegate.DynamicInvoke - catch exception

Tags: c#, exception, delegates

I'm calling a delegate (dynamically configurable service) using:

```
public void CallService (Delegate service, IContext ctx)
{
    var serviceArgs = CreateServiceArguments(service, ctx);
    service.DynamicInvoke(serviceArgs);
}
```

At this point I want to catch all exceptions that occurred in the called service method, however, I do not want to catch any exception that occurred due to the DynamicInvoke call. E.g.:

- `service` delegate throws `DomainException` -> catch the exception
- `DynamicInvoke()` throws `MemberAccessException` because the delegate is a private method -> do not catch the exception, let it bubble up

I hope it is clear what I'm asking. How to decide whether a catched exception originates from the DynamicInvoke call itself or from the underlying delegate.

Oh yeah, and: I cannot use the exception type to decide! It is completely possible that the service itself throws a MemberAccessException as well, because it could do some delegate stuff itself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Oh yeah, and: I cannot use the exception type to decide! It is completely possible that the service itself throws a MemberAccessException as well, because it could do some delegate stuff itself...

Yes, you can use the exception type to decide. As mentioned in the documentation for `Delegate.DynamicInvoke`, if the method being called throws an exception (any exception), it will be wrapped in a `TargetInvocationException`. That is the exception you can catch, and you can then look at its `InnerException` property to know whether it's an exception you can deal with.